# find previous and next observation in r

Tags: r

Here is the head of my data.frame,df in r. There is no pattern in any row or column.

```
         Type SIZE      V1   V2    
          A    1        5    7      
          B    1        NA   NA
          B    3        NA   NA
          B    4        NA   NA     
          A    8        2    4      
          A    6        6    50      
          A    12       2    8       
          B    8        NA   NA      
          A    9        51   63       
          A    11       93   70
```

For each row that df$Type == "B", I want to find the previous and next row with df$Type =="A", then extract their "V1", and "V2".

Desired output,

```
         Type SIZE      V1   V2   V1_lag   V2_lag   V1_lead   V2_lead
          A    1        5    7      NA       NA        NA       NA
          B    1        NA   NA     5        7         2        4
          B    3        NA   NA     5        7         2        4
          B    4        NA   NA     5        7         2        4
          A    8        2    4      NA       NA        NA       NA
          A    6        6    50     NA       NA        NA       NA
          A    12       2    8      NA       NA        NA       NA
          B    8        NA   NA     2        8         51       63
          A    9        51   63     NA       NA        NA       NA  
          A    11       93   70     NA       NA        NA       NA
```

Thank you so much if someone could help on this,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example by first storing the indices where `type` is `A`.. e.g.,

```
dat <- data.frame(type = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A"),
                  size = c(1, 1, 3, 4, 8, 6, 12, 8, 9, 11),
                  v1 = c(5, NA, NA, NA, 2, 6, 2, NA, 51, 93),
                  v2 = c(7, NA, NA, NA, 4, 50, 8, NA, 63, 70))

dat$idx <- 1:nrow(dat)
a_idx <- which(dat$type == "A")
b_idx <- which(dat$type == "B")
```

You can then easily find the last one / next one where it is `B` with `>` and `<`... with `sapply`,

```
new <- sapply(b_idx, function(x) {
  lag_idx <- tail(a_idx[a_idx < x], 1)
  lead_idx <- head(a_idx[a_idx > x], 1)

  return (t(c(dat$v1[lag_idx], dat$v2[lag_idx], 
            dat$v1[lead_idx], dat$v2[lead_idx])))
  }
)

new <- t(new)
new <- cbind(new, b_idx)
colnames(new) <- c("V1_Lag", "V2_Lag", "V1_Lead", "V2_Lead", "idx")
merge(dat, new, all = TRUE)

   idx type size v1 v2 V1_Lag V2_Lag V1_Lead V2_Lead
1    1    A    1  5  7     NA     NA      NA      NA
2    2    B    1 NA NA      5      7       2       4
3    3    B    3 NA NA      5      7       2       4
4    4    B    4 NA NA      5      7       2       4
5    5    A    8  2  4     NA     NA      NA      NA
6    6    A    6  6 50     NA     NA      NA      NA
7    7    A   12  2  8     NA     NA      NA      NA
8    8    B    8 NA NA      2      8      51      63
9    9    A    9 51 63     NA     NA      NA      NA
10  10    A   11 93 70     NA     NA      NA      NA
```

Answer (score 1):

With this data

```
dat <- data.frame(
    type = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A"),
    size = c(1, 1, 3, 4, 8, 6, 12, 8, 9, 11),
    v1 = c(5, NA, NA, NA, 2, 6, 2, NA, 51, 93),
    v2 = c(7, NA, NA, NA, 4, 50, 8, NA, 63, 70),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

calculate the 'run length encoding' of the `type` column

```
r <- rle(dat$type)
```

with

```
> r
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:5] 1 3 3 1 2
  values : chr [1:5] "A" "B" "A" "B" "A"
```

(i.e., 1 A, then 3 B, 3 A, 1 B, and 2 A). The index of the lagging values are

```
lag <- setdiff(
    cumsum(r$lengths)[r$values == "A"],
    nrow(dat)   # ignore "A" value at end of column
)
```

Each lagging value needs to be replicated, with the new value `v1lag` populated as

```
value <- rep(dat$v1[lag], r$length[r$value == "B"])
```

A similar story plays out with the leading value

```
lead <- pmin(
    cumsum(r$lengths)[r$values == "B"] + 1L,
    nrow(dat)   # ignore "B" value at end of column
)
value <- rep(dat$v1[lead], r$length[r$value == "B"])
```

An implementation for the specific problem is

```
mm <- function(df) {
    r <- rle(df$type)
    lag <- setdiff(cumsum(r$lengths)[r$values == "A"], nrow(df))
    lead <- pmin(cumsum(r$lengths)[r$values == "B"] + 1L, nrow(df))
    len <- r$length[r$value == "B"]

    idx <- df$type == "B"
    df$v1_lag[idx] <- rep(df$v1[lag], len)
    df$v2_lag[idx] <- rep(df$v2[lag], len)
    df$v1_lead[idx] <- rep(df$v1[lead], len)
    df$v2_lead[idx] <- rep(df$v2[lead], len)

    df
}
```

This will be faster and more robust than erocoar's solution.